# Completely positive maps with commuting ranges can be extended to maximal tensor product

Tags: c-star-algebras, tensor-products, complete-positivity

I'm trying to do the following exercise from Brown and Ozawa's book.

> Exercise $3.5.1.$ Let $\varphi: A \to B(H)$ and $\psi: B \to B(H)$ be
>   c.p. maps with commuting ranges. Show that there exists a c.p. map
>   $\varphi \times_{max} \psi: A \otimes_{max} B \to B(H)$ such that
>   $\varphi \times_{max} \psi(a\otimes b)=\varphi(a)\psi(b)$ for all
>   $a\in A$  and $b\in B$.

Maybe it worth mention that I didn't read the chapters regarding c.p. maps and I know just Stinespring Theorem and the definition of c.p. maps. 
So, I'm afraid this is the reason that no solution coming to my mind.
However, I hope that I just need to use continuity of tensor products, Stinespring Theorem + "lifting of commutant", and universality of the maximal tensor product.

However, I don't know how to collect the above to solution.
I prefer a hint than a full-solution,
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Stinespring's theorem for this. How this could work (without details):

At first you get a map $\varphi\times \psi:A\odot B\to B(H), a\otimes b\mapsto \varphi(a)\psi (b)$, where $A\odot B$ is the $*$-algebraic tensor product of $A$ and $B$. To extend $\varphi\times \psi$ to a map on $A\otimes_{max}B$ you can do the following: Prove that this map is positive ( for this you need that the ranges of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ commute). Then for every positive linear functional $\eta :B(H)\to \mathbb{C}$ the composition $\eta \circ (\varphi\times \psi):A\odot B\to \mathbb{C}$ extends uniquely  to a positive linear functional on $A\otimes_{max}B$. Conclude that there exists a well-defined map $$\Gamma: B(H)^*\to (A\otimes_{max}B)^*,\; \eta \mapsto \eta \circ (\varphi\times \psi),$$where $B(H)^*$ denotes the bounded linear functionals on $B(H)$. This map is bounded (use closed graph theorem for this), thus $\varphi\times \psi$ extends to a bounded map $\varphi\times_{max} \psi:A\otimes_{max}B\to B(H)$. 
To prove that this map is completely positive, fix an arbitrary $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and prove that $$(\varphi\times_{max} \psi)^{(n)}:M_n(A\otimes_{max}B)\to M_n(B(H)),\; (z_{ij})_{i,j}\mapsto (\varphi\times_{max} \psi (z_{ij}))_{ij}$$ is positive. To do this, note that the product of commuting positive elements is again positive.

Regards